# Apache HttpClient execute method without Host port number

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

We are creating a reverse proxy application in java which just forwards requests to downstream systems and gets response and sends it back to UI.

For this we started using Apache HttpClient library. Http client execute works perfectly when we configure like below. It is handling all requests (GET,POST,PUT,DELETE). It was made on generic way.

```
 HttpRequest request = null;
    if (request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH) != null
                    || request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.TRANSFER_ENCODING) != null) {
        HttpEntityEnclosingRequest proxyRequest = new BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest(method, requestUri);
        proxyRequest.setEntity(new InputStreamEntity(servletRequest.getInputStream(), getContentLength(servletRequest)));

    } else {
        proxyRequest = new BasicHttpRequest(method, requestUri);
    }
    request = proxyRequest;
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpHost("http://custdomain.com", 8443, "https"),request);
```

But when i try to use only url without port number, i m not able to connect to downstream system.

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpHost("http://custdomain.com",-1, "https"),request);
```

Suggestions please.

Edit1: while connecting to 8443 port i m getting connection reset exception

```
2018-08-03 17:22:28.961 DEBUG 7920 --- [nio-9003-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> CONNECT quotesystem.com:8443 HTTP/1.1
2018-08-03 17:22:28.966 DEBUG 7920 --- [nio-9003-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> Host: quotesystem.com:8443
2018-08-03 17:22:28.971 DEBUG 7920 --- [nio-9003-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_131)
2018-08-03 17:22:28.976 DEBUG 7920 --- [nio-9003-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "CONNECT quotesystem.com:8443 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2018-08-03 17:22:28.981 DEBUG 7920 --- [nio-9003-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: quotesystem.com:8443[\r][\n]"
2018-08-03 17:22:28.986 DEBUG 7920 --- [nio-9003-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_131)[\r][\n]"
2018-08-03 17:22:28.988 DEBUG 7920 --- [nio-9003-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
2018-08-03 17:22:29.018 DEBUG 7920 --- [nio-9003-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established[\r][\n]"
2018-08-03 17:22:29.023 DEBUG 7920 --- [nio-9003-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "Proxy-Agent: Zscaler/6.0[\r][\n]"
2018-08-03 17:22:29.026 DEBUG 7920 --- [nio-9003-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
2018-08-03 17:22:29.081 DEBUG 7920 --- [nio-9003-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
2018-08-03 17:22:29.086 DEBUG 7920 --- [nio-9003-exec-1] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << Proxy-Agent: Zscaler/6.0
2018-08-03 17:22:29.123 DEBUG 7920 --- [nio-9003-exec-1] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Tunnel to target created.
2018-08-03 17:22:35.686 DEBUG 7920 --- [nio-9003-exec-1] o.a.h.c.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory   : Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
2018-08-03 17:22:35.689 DEBUG 7920 --- [nio-9003-exec-1] o.a.h.c.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory   : Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
2018-08-03 17:22:35.694 DEBUG 7920 --- [nio-9003-exec-1] o.a.h.c.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory   : Starting handshake
2018-08-03 17:23:11.553 DEBUG 7920 --- [nio-9003-exec-1] h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection : http-outgoing-0: Shutdown connection
2018-08-03 17:23:11.569 DEBUG 7920 --- [nio-9003-exec-1] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Connection discarded
2018-08-03 17:23:11.584 DEBUG 7920 --- [nio-9003-exec-1] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection released: [id: 0][route: {tls}->http://127.0.0.1:9874->https://quotesystem.com:8443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 100]
2018-08-03 17:23:11.619  INFO 7920 --- [nio-9003-exec-1] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {tls}->http://127.0.0.1:9874->https://quotesystem.com:8443: Connection reset
2018-08-03 17:23:11.849 DEBUG 7920 --- [nio-9003-exec-1] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : Connection reset


java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.upgrade(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:193) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.upgrade(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:375) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:416) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111) [httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) [httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) [httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) [httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
```

Comment: why do you think it should work without port number?

Answer (score 2):

Resolved this issue by enabling TLSv1.2

Comment: > `Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]` I suppose what needs to be done is forcing HttpClient to enable `SSLv3` as well

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, your downsystem is available to be connected to via `https` on `8443` port. When you create request to it using `new HttpHost("http://custdomain.com", 8443, "https")`, you explicitly mention you want to connect to `8443` port. But when you use `new HttpHost("http://custdomain.com", -1, "https")`, you leave Apache HttpClient to decide to [which port it should connect](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpHost.html#HttpHost(java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String)) - as you can see, Apache HttpClient connects to default scheme (`https` in your case) port. In Apache HttpClient 4.x this port is resolved using [`SchemePortResolver`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/SchemePortResolver.html) instance. [Default implementation of it](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/tags/4.5.3/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/conn/DefaultSchemePortResolver.java) returns hardcoded value for https scheme - and it's `443` port, that's why you cannot connect.

I guess you cannot run your downsystem on `443` port unless you're root - so, you should request for the port explicitly. If you want to leave Apache Http Client to construct it, you can write you own implementation of [`SchemePortResolver`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/SchemePortResolver.html) and set it into `HttpClientBuilder` using [`setSchemePortResolver`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html#setSchemePortResolver(org.apache.http.conn.SchemePortResolver)) method.